# red outline displays on Combobox in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am having an Wpf application it has a Combobox.
which contains a checkbox and Textblock when i click on the checkbox 
it shows the selected country string in the combobox but if i click on text it shows me a error string as shown in image.
I want to show the country name even if the user clicks on the textblock.

[image]

My xaml looks like this

```
                <ComboBox   Text="{Binding CurrentCountries}"  ToolTip="{Binding CurrentCountries}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="cmbCountry" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"  TextSearch.TextPath="{Binding CountryName}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Margin="80,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100 " ItemsSource="{Binding Country, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry,Mode= TwoWay}" Height="22" TabIndex="1">

                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="Country"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0"   Content="{Binding CountryName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                        <Commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.CountryCheckedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Country}" ></Commands:EventToCommand>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                        <Commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.CountryUnCheckedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Country}" ></Commands:EventToCommand>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
```

thank you!

Comment: Why do you need the checkbox? Are you trying to build a combobox that allows you to select multiple items?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://www.dotnetperls.com/combobox-wpf buy the way as @sga101 asked, why do you need a checkbox within?

Comment: I required check box to allow multi selection

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiselection ComboBox you should use [CheckComboBox](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckComboBox&referringTitle=Home) from [WPF Extended Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).

It's very easy to using, example:

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox x:Name="_combo" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   DisplayMemberPath="Color"
                   ValueMemberPath="Level"
                   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"
                   SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
```